# Browser detection & Firefox data-src attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firefox, iframe

I'm looking to embed browser detection on my page so that if the browser is Firefox, I launch a different iframe (difference is the data-src vs src) as shown here. Can someone help me what I need to change in the script section to make it work?

```
 <script>
 // Firefox 1.0+
 var isFirefox = typeof InstallTrigger !== 'undefined';


 isFF = '<iframe width="806" height="634" frameborder="0" scrolling="0" scrolling="no" horizontalscrolling="no"  verticalscrolling="no" **src**="../test.html"></iframe>';

notFF = '<iframe width="806" height="634" frameborder="0" scrolling="0" scrolling="no" horizontalscrolling="no"  verticalscrolling="no" **data-src**="../test.html"></iframe>';

if(isFirefox = 'true') {

  window.load(isFF);
 }else {
  window.load(notFF);
}

</script>
```

Comment: How do you define "Firefox", exactly? Do you include Palemoon, Thunderbird and Gecko based browsers? What if I download the source code, modify a tiny bit of code and compile it myself?

Comment: Never do browser sniffing. Use feature detection instead.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using Jquery for anyone else's reference:

```
<script>

// Firefox 1.0+

if (isFirefox = typeof InstallTrigger !== 'undefined') {


$(function() {

     $("#browser-iframe iframe").replaceWith(function(){
        return $('<iframe class="auto-resize" width="860" height="530" frameborder="0" scrolling="0" scrolling="no" horizontalscrolling="no"  verticalscrolling="no" src="../youtubevideo.html"></iframe>');
    });


});

}
</script>
```

With the replaceWith, I replaced the code I wanted.

Comment: Checking `InstallTrigger` seems so unreliable. `navigator.userAgent` seems a better idea.